# Slime material shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I've tried to make a slimeish shader that looks as close as possible to the reference bellow.

But one thing that i keep struggling with is getting the effect right where its more see trough in the thinner smoother bits and darker in the more detail denser/thicker bits.

Ive tried several slime and plastic shaders: I've come close, but this thickness effect is something im not able to reproduce.

I'm not going to share any attempts as there are many and they are convoluted setups. Ive tried volume absorptions, transmission, translucency mixed with glossy and many other things but.

I'm wondering how to make it from scratch.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most complicated material... Simple Glass shader and some volume absorption would do just fine. It seems there is some sort of finish on top of the plastic because of less rough reflections, so I added a glossy shader on top of the glass, but that's very subtle:

[image]

Its not only the material that gives it this look. Lighting and form are important things here. Make sure you light your subject well, maybe use HDRI like I did in the screenshot and also in order for the effect to be visible, you have to have thick and thin parts in your model...

Comment: That looks good. Do you mind sharing your file so that i can inspect more whats going wrong here.

Since idk how to set up the light for this kind of shader, and it would be easier for me to just look at yours and reverse engineer it.


EDIT: I also just noticed that scale changes things a lot as well.

And the texture is also important, thats the hard part. Ive gotten most things down allready, except the proper way the density works, especially in the face

Comment: Sorry, I did not save it. It's really nothing special, just HDRI from HDRI Haven, a plane and a monkey -  that's it.

Comment: How easy u find it dosnt help me.

Anyhow I was able to somewhat recreate it. And i dont feel it hits the point properly. 

I will move on because I think what im requesting dosnt work well for this format and might be a bit to specific to get into details about here3+

Comment: Sorry, I know it's different when you are learning something, but this is not only how I personally find it. Those are 4 values only you need to work with here: Glass color, glass roughness, absorption color and absorption density. It's not unreasonable to call it easy. Developing artistic look is harder, but I cannot help with that, only with using the tools.

Comment: Yes thats why i decided to close the thread. As i realised the fidelity i desire is a bit much to request here.

,In my head theres more than 4 possible values to making it exactly like i want to, theres a multitude of different combinations and shaders you can use to get similar but slightly different effects. So since i've not found exactly what I want, then it is more complex then only 4 shaders.

Anyways, what you offered helped me in the right direction, and I thank you for that ^^